# Solution around gradle cache issues with snapshots?

Tags: maven, gradle

When publishing snapshots to artifactory/mavenLocal, projects won't pick up the latest snapshot. This requires deleting the jar from ~/.gradle/cache

Maven has a feature to set timestamps for snapshots. how would this work with gradle cache?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to consider in resolving your issue:

1. How Gradle handles/recognizes snapshots
2. How to override Gradle's default behavior

#### Some background on how Gradle recognizes/handles snapshots

By default, Gradle will refresh a snapshot dependency every 24 hours.

Gradle will automatically recognize a dependency as a snapshot if the version ends with the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "aGroup", name: "anArtifact", version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

However, if the dependency's version string does not end with `-SNAPSHOT` Gradle needs to be told it's a snapshot with the `changing` parameter. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "aGroup", name: "anArtifact", version: "1.0", changing: true
}
```

#### Overriding how often Gradle downloads snapshots

The only mechanism for overriding the default 24 hour policy is to configure Gradle to invalidate dependency cache (and thus download a new SNAPSHOT) more frequently. For example:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

#### Dynamically versioned dependency cache will need to be configured separately

If you're using any dynamic versions, such as:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "aGroup", name: "anArtifact", version: "1.+", changing: true
}
```

You'll need to configure cache invalidation for those dependencies separately, like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

#### Build performance impact

One thing to note is that the shorter the period of time a dependency is cached the more frequently Gradle will retrieve that artifact. If caching is disabled altogether, it will grab the dependency during each execution.

Comment: why cacheChangingModulesFor and cacheDynamicVersionsFor both are necessary? is there any difference between them.